# How to deliver parameter from command line into rust kernel module?

Tags: rust, linux-kernel

I want to pass some params to rust linux kernel module. In C language, I can use `module_param()`. But I can't find a functional equivalent method in rust kernel.

I found similar method called `kernel::miscdev::Registration::register_with_options()`. But it needs a `Options` struct and that can only be created in kernel codes.

So, is there any way to pass parameters from cmd line to rust kernel module?